# Getting low and high parts of the 16-bit word

Tags: assembly, z80, sdcc

Learning SDCC compiler, its Z80 part (sdasz80). In native versions of assembler I use:

```
ld (hl),LOW BUF
inc hl
ld (hl),HIGH BUF
```

to store 16-bit value `BUF` in two 8-bit parts (high and low). I can not find how to do it in SDCC, it seems this

```
ld  (hl),#BUF & #0xff
inc hl
ld  (hl),#BUF >> 8 & #0xff
```

compiles without error, with the code produced being correct, but the second load does not look good for me, and no brackets to order the logical operations are accepted by compiler. Is it correct, and the only way to achieve split of 16-bit value by 2 bytes?

Update. Found in some ASxxx [manuals](http://k1.spdns.de/Develop/Hardware/AVR/mixed%20docs.../doc/as/asxhtm.html) `>` and `<` operators (see table 4). Do not work giving compile errors "Error:  machine specific addressing or addressing mode error".

Update1:
The following code

```
BUF .equ    #0xf55e
....
ld  (hl),`HI(BUF)
```

gives an error `Error: <q> missing or improper operators, terminators, or delimiters`.

Comment: Presumably that assembler uses a different operator precedence than C.  In C, that would be `BUF >> (8 & 0xff)`, but if it works then obviously it means `(BUF >> 8) & 0xff`.  The `& 0xFF` is redundant, unless `#BUF` is actually larger than 16-bit.

Comment: IDK why you mention `>` and `<` operators, unless there's some reason to expect that they would be shifts instead of compares even though there's only one angle-bracket.

Comment: @PeterCordes: From the linked manual: _"<   Left bracket        <FEDC   Produces  the lower byte value of the expression. (DC)"_

Comment: Not sure if this is for the assembler you have, but try  HI(BUF) and LO(BUF) with 'back apostrophy' in front of HI and LO (the engine here does not allow to show it).

Comment: apostrophe.. "back quote" - coded with 0x60 in ascii is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @tum_: you can use triple-backquote code blocks in comments, allowing backquotes inside code formatting, but that doesn't work when the first char would be a backtick.  Or you can use backslash to escape them inside single backticks. but that fails for a single back *slash* ``\`` (I got that with `\`\`\\\`\``).  Backslash inside backticks works for a single backtick `\`` or   `\`HI(BUF)`

Comment: Cheers, @Peter. Considering how often one needs to use a backtick in a comment the chances of remembering this are close to zero :) And considering the time slot you are given to edit a comment, figuring this out by trial and error is also quite a challenge. I just gave up.

Comment: Back quote gives an error "Error: <q> missing or improper operators, terminators, or delimiters"

Comment: Is there any official support for SDCC that you could possibly try? Other than that, if your #BUF>>8 trick works - why not use it.. There is also an option to disassemble the tool and reverse-engineer.

Comment: http://svn.code.sf.net/p/sdcc/code/trunk/sdcc/sdas/doc/asmlnk.txt - table 5
& is a logical AND and not a bitwise AND
The < and > look like they should work.

But to keep it simple, high = divide (/) by 256, low = modulo (%) 256 - be sure to check that divide is an integer divide and does not add sneaky rounding.